# Is there a way to get out of a "hung" state in IRB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, irb

When using `irb` or `rails console`, I sometimes get stuck. For example, I forget a closing quote, so when I press enter, it's still waiting on that.

Sometimes I can get out of this (by suppyling the closing quote, for example), but sometimes I can't. If not, I usually do the following:

```
# Suspend the irb or console process
(Control + Z)

# Kill the last suspended process
kill -9 %
```

This is annoying and disrupts whatever I was doing in the console. What I'd like is an equivalent to `Control + C` on the command line, to say "forget that - give me a new prompt", so I can continue working in the console.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Control + C normally does the trick for me i must admit.

Comment: @zoltarSpeaks - doesn't that kick you out of the console?

Comment: @Nathan nope. `Control + D` does (when entered enough times). It quits you also from terminal session, ssh session, su and all other types of sessions.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Press `Control + D` once or twice. That should do it.

Comment: D for Dogbert? :) That seems to work. Do you know what it's actually doing?

Comment: :D. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file Control+D sends an EOF character to the stream.

Comment: Interesting. So I guess this fits with the "everything in Unix is a file" philosophy - my current terminal input included.

Comment: Interesting, I always thought that `ctrl + D` stood for disconnect.

Answer (score 0):

when you get recursion or Ctrl+D doesn't work

you can kill current process (`$$`)

```
exec("kill -9 #{$$}")
```