# Command line / IRB won't return values - Ruby

Tags: ruby, command-line, terminal, irb

When I use irb in the command line for ruby, sometimes it won't return any values.  This seems to be happening after I've made a typo or entered incorrect code.

How do I exit this mode and go back to using irb normally?  It won't let me quit with the 'quit' command, and I have to shut down the command line / Terminal and go back into it.

When this happens in vim you can press esc ! q n enter in sequence and it brings you back into the editor.

I've attached a screen shot showing what happens  - as you can see it won't return any value for i in this instance.

Thanks
[image]

Comment: With _Ctrl_ + _C_ obviously.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358135/is-there-a-way-to-get-out-of-a-hung-state-in-irb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This occurs when you have entered an incomplete expression that requires closing characters of some kind to complete it. Example:

[image: Incomplete expression in IRB]

The `?` in the prompt indicates that the REPL is waiting on closing characters to evaluate the expression.

You can exit this state by completing the expression or by aborting its evaluation with *Ctrl+c*.